# setting up uWSGI and Django app

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am trying to follow the steps in this guide:  http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Before  I even get to the nginx part I am trying to make sure that uWSGI works correctly

my folder structure is srv/www/domain/projectdatabank/

the project databank folder contains my manage.py file

my wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "databank.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

i go into the projectdatabank folder and run the following command

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file projectdatabank/databank/wsgi.py
```

when i go to the web page i get this error

```
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) on 06 July 2013 00:16:13
os: Linux-3.8.4-linode50 #1 SMP Mon Mar 25 15:50:29 EDT 2013
nodename: 
machine: i686
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /srv/www/databankinfo.com
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 1024
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 10091)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:47129 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 21 2013, 23:54:59)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x8cf8598
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 64000 bytes (62 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x8cf8598 pid: 10090 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 10090, cores: 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'databank.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named databank.settings
[pid: 10090|app: 0|req: 1/1] 66.56.35.151 () {38 vars in 669 bytes} [Tue Jul  9 17:34:52 2013] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

however I know that settings.py exists in the same directory as wsgi.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an additional argument to your `uwsgi` call:

```
--chdir /path/to/your/project/
```

Comment: thanks! that got me along but now i get an internal server error, guess ill open up another question with thanks...thanks again!